# Matrix size-incompatible: In[0]: [10,3500], In[1]: [9,9] [Op:MatMul] (Autoencoder)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, autoencoder, invalidargumentexception

I'm working with neural networks and  I'm new in this field. I am implementing an autoencoder for text data. The problem starts when I execute the fit function for Variational Autoencoder. Code snippets are

```
text_input_shape                 = (encoder(tweets_dna).shape[1], )
text_input_diensions             = len(encoder.get_vocabulary())
text_embedding_output_dimensions = 64

text_input_shape

encoder_input = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=text_input_shape, dtype='float32', name="TF_input")
encoder_embedded = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(input_dim=text_input_diensions, dtype='float32', output_dim=text_embedding_output_dimensions, mask_zero=True, name="Encoder_Embedding")(encoder_input)
LTSM_layer, state_h, state_c = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(text_embedding_output_dimensions, dtype='float32', return_state=True, name="LTSM")(encoder_embedded)
dense_layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(text_embedding_output_dimensions, dtype='float32', activation='relu', name="Compression")(LTSM_layer)
final_layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(text_input_diensions, dtype='float32', activation='relu', name="Lossy_Compression")(dense_layer)
text_mu = tf.keras.layers.Dense(text_input_diensions, dtype='float32', name='latent_mu')(final_layer)
text_sigma = tf.keras.layers.Dense(text_input_diensions, dtype='float32', name='latent_sigma')(final_layer)

text_encoder_states = [state_h, state_c]

def sample_z(args):
    mu, sigma = args
    batch     = tf.keras.backend.shape(mu)[0]
    dim       = tf.keras.backend.int_shape(mu)[1]
    eps       = tf.keras.backend.random_normal(shape=(batch, dim))
    return text_mu + tf.keras.backend.exp(sigma / 2) * eps

text_z = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(sample_z, output_shape=(len(encoder.get_vocabulary()), ), name='z')([text_mu, text_sigma])

text_encoder = tf.keras.Model(encoder_input, [text_mu, text_sigma, text_z], name='TextCompressionModel')

# Decoder
decoder_input = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(text_input_diensions, ), dtype='float32', name='decoder_input')
decoder_embedded = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(input_dim=text_input_diensions, dtype='float32', output_dim=64, mask_zero=True)(decoder_input)
LTSM_layer = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(64, dtype='float32')(decoder_embedded)
final_output_dense = tf.keras.layers.Dense(MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGHT, dtype='float32')(LTSM_layer)

text_decoder = tf.keras.Model(decoder_input, final_output_dense, name='TextDecoder')

# Instantiate VAE
tweet_vae_outputs = text_decoder(text_encoder(encoder_input)[2])
tweets_vae = tf.keras.Model(encoder_input, tweet_vae_outputs, name='Text-VAE')

def tweets_kl_reconstruction_loss(true, pred):
    # Reconstruction loss
    reconstruction_loss = binary_crossentropy(K.flatten(true), K.flatten(pred)) * input_shape[0]
    # KL divergence loss
    kl_loss = -0.5 * (1 + sigma - K.square(mu) - K.exp(sigma))
    kl_loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.reduce_sum(kl_loss, axis=1))
    # Total loss = 50% rec + 50% KL divergence loss
    return (reconstruction_loss + kl_loss)

tweets_reconstruction_loss = tf.function(tweets_kl_reconstruction_loss)

tweets_vae.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=tweets_reconstruction_loss)

history = vae.fit(x = tweet_data, y = tweet_data, 
        epochs = no_epochs, 
        batch_size = batch_size, 
        validation_split = validation_split)
```

The error is:

> Epoch 1/10
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in 
> ----> 1 history = vae.fit(x = tweet_data, y = tweet_data,
> 2         epochs = no_epochs,
> 3         batch_size = batch_size,
> 4         validation_split = validation_split)
>
> c:\users\bilal\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py
> in _method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)
> 106   def _method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
> 107     if not self._in_multi_worker_mode():  # pylint: disable=protected-access
> --> 108       return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
> 109
> 110     # Running inside `run_distribute_coordinator` already.
>
> c:\users\bilal\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py
> in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks,
> validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight,
> sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps,
> validation_batch_size, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers,
> use_multiprocessing)    1096                 batch_size=batch_size):
> 1097               callbacks.on_train_batch_begin(step)
> -> 1098               tmp_logs = train_function(iterator)    1099               if data_handler.should_sync:    1100
> context.async_wait()
>
> c:\users\bilal\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py
> in train_function(iterator)
> 804       def train_function(iterator):
> 805         """Runs a training execution with one step."""
> --> 806         return step_function(self, iterator)
> 807
> 808     else:
>
> c:\users\bilal\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py
> in step_function(model, iterator)
> 794
> 795       data = next(iterator)
> --> 796       outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
> 797       outputs = reduce_per_replica(
> 798           outputs, self.distribute_strategy, reduction='first')
>
> c:\users\bilal\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py
> in run(***failed resolving arguments***)    1209       fn =
> autograph.tf_convert(    1210           fn,
> autograph_ctx.control_status_ctx(), convert_by_default=False)
> -> 1211       return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)    1212     1213   # TODO(b/151224785):
> Remove deprecated alias.
>
> c:\users\bilal\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py
> in call_for_each_replica(self, fn, args, kwargs)    2583       kwargs
> = {}    2584     with self._container_strategy().scope():
> -> 2585       return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)    2586     2587   def _call_for_each_replica(self, fn, args, kwargs):
>
> c:\users\bilal\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py
> in _call_for_each_replica(self, fn, args, kwargs)    2943
> self._container_strategy(),    2944
> replica_id_in_sync_group=constant_op.constant(0, dtypes.int32)):
> -> 2945       return fn(*args, **kwargs)    2946     2947   def _reduce_to(self, reduce_op, value, destinations, experimental_hints):
>
> c:\users\bilal\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\autograph\impl\api.py
> in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
> 273   def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
> 274     with ag_ctx.ControlStatusCtx(status=ag_ctx.Status.UNSPECIFIED):
> --> 275       return func(*args, **kwargs)
> 276
> 277   if inspect.isfunction(func) or inspect.ismethod(func):
>
> c:\users\bilal\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py
> in run_step(data)
> 787
> 788       def run_step(data):
> --> 789         outputs = model.train_step(data)
> 790         # Ensure counter is updated only if `train_step` succeeds.
> 791         with ops.control_dependencies(_minimum_control_deps(outputs)):
>
> c:\users\bilal\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py
> in train_step(self, data)
> 745
> 746     with backprop.GradientTape() as tape:
> --> 747       y_pred = self(x, training=True)
> 748       loss = self.compiled_loss(
> 749           y, y_pred, sample_weight, regularization_losses=self.losses)
>
> c:\users\bilal\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\base_layer.py
> in **call**(self, *args, **kwargs)
> 983
> 984         with ops.enable_auto_cast_variables(self._compute_dtype_object):
> --> 985           outputs = call_fn(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
> 986
> 987         if self._activity_regularizer:
>
> c:\users\bilal\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\functional.py
> in call(self, inputs, training, mask)
> 383         a list of tensors if there are more than one outputs.
> 384     """
> --> 385     return self._run_internal_graph(
> 386         inputs, training=training, mask=mask)
> 387
>
> c:\users\bilal\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\functional.py
> in _run_internal_graph(self, inputs, training, mask)
> 506
> 507         args, kwargs = node.map_arguments(tensor_dict)
> --> 508         outputs = node.layer(*args, **kwargs)
> 509
> 510         # Update tensor_dict.
>
> c:\users\bilal\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\base_layer.py
> in **call**(self, *args, **kwargs)
> 983
> 984         with ops.enable_auto_cast_variables(self._compute_dtype_object):
> --> 985           outputs = call_fn(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
> 986
> 987         if self._activity_regularizer:
>
> c:\users\bilal\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\functional.py
> in call(self, inputs, training, mask)
> 383         a list of tensors if there are more than one outputs.
> 384     """
> --> 385     return self._run_internal_graph(
> 386         inputs, training=training, mask=mask)
> 387
>
> c:\users\bilal\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\functional.py
> in _run_internal_graph(self, inputs, training, mask)
> 506
> 507         args, kwargs = node.map_arguments(tensor_dict)
> --> 508         outputs = node.layer(*args, **kwargs)
> 509
> 510         # Update tensor_dict.
>
> c:\users\bilal\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\base_layer.py
> in **call**(self, *args, **kwargs)
> 983
> 984         with ops.enable_auto_cast_variables(self._compute_dtype_object):
> --> 985           outputs = call_fn(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
> 986
> 987         if self._activity_regularizer:
>
> c:\users\bilal\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\layers\core.py
> in call(self, inputs)    1191     1192   def call(self, inputs):
> -> 1193     return core_ops.dense(    1194         inputs,    1195         self.kernel,
>
> c:\users\bilal\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\layers\ops\core.py
> in dense(inputs, kernel, bias, activation, dtype)
> 51       outputs = sparse_ops.sparse_tensor_dense_matmul(inputs, kernel)
> 52     else:
> ---> 53       outputs = gen_math_ops.mat_mul(inputs, kernel)
> 54   # Broadcast kernel to inputs.
> 55   else:
>
> c:\users\bilal\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_math_ops.py
> in mat_mul(a, b, transpose_a, transpose_b, name)    5622       return
> _result    5623     except _core._NotOkStatusException as e:
> -> 5624       _ops.raise_from_not_ok_status(e, name)    5625     except _core._FallbackException:    5626       pass
>
> c:\users\bilal\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py
> in raise_from_not_ok_status(e, name)    6841   message = e.message +
> (" name: " + name if name is not None else "")    6842   # pylint:
> disable=protected-access
> -> 6843   six.raise_from(core._status_to_exception(e.code, message), None)    6844   # pylint: enable=protected-access    6845
>
> ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\six.py in
> raise_from(value, from_value)
>
> InvalidArgumentError: Matrix size-incompatible: In[0]: [10,3500],
> In[1](https://github.com/UsamaMalick/Spotting-Fake-users-on-Twitter/blob/main/notebooks/sfuot.ipynb): [9,9] [Op:MatMul]

I'm new to this field. And I am not sure if my implementation is correct because I have no idea where that In[1](https://github.com/UsamaMalick/Spotting-Fake-users-on-Twitter/blob/main/notebooks/sfuot.ipynb): [9,9] is coming from. Moreover, this GitHub link goes to the [executed notebook](https://github.com/UsamaMalick/Spotting-Fake-users-on-Twitter/blob/main/notebooks/sfuot.ipynb) of the complete code. Please help.

Comment: What is `encoder` object ?

Comment: This is a layer from Keras, which is being used to generate vocabulary and indexing. Here is the code of that part.

VOCAB_SIZE = 5
MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGHT = 3500
encoder = tf.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing.TextVectorization(
    max_tokens=VOCAB_SIZE, output_sequence_length=MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGHT)
encoder.adapt(tweets_dna)